# each option in select tag disable a specific element in page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, html-select

I'm trying to implement a form in which you choose a shape from a `select` tag and it calculates the area and perimeter.
I just want when I select the Square option from the `select`, radius input disabled like the image.

**Please do not use JQuery**

**Please do not use JQuery**

**Please do not use JQuery**

[image]

here is my form please help me with *`.js`* file

```
<div class="container">
    <hr class="lighter">
    <label for="shapes">Shapes :</label>
    <select name="shapes" id="shapes">
        <option value="rectangle">Rectangle</option>
        <option value="square">Square</option>
        <option value="circle">Circle</option>
        <option value="cylindrical">Cylindrical</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <lable for="radius">Radius : </lable>
    <input type="number" id="radius" disabled><br>
    <lable for="shapeWidth">Widht : </lable>
    <input type="number" id="shapeWidth"><br>
    <lable for="shapeHeight">Height :</lable>
    <input type="number" id="shapeHeight">
    <hr>
    <label for="area" id="area_result">Area :</label>
    <label for="area_result"></label>
    <br>
    <label for="primiter" id="primiter_result">Primiter :</label>
    <label for="primiter_result"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+-jquery+select+disable+input+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: fyi: it is spelled `label` - not `lable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const eleId = document.getElementById("shapes");
const radiusId = document.getElementById("radius");
eleId.addEventListener(
  "change",
  function () {
    if (this.value === "square") {
      radiusId.disabled = true;
    } else {
      radiusId.disabled = false;
    }
  },
)
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <hr class="lighter" />
  <label for="shapes">Shapes :</label>
  <select name="shapes" id="shapes">
    <option value="rectangle">Rectangle</option>
    <option value="square">Square</option>
    <option value="circle">Circle</option>
    <option value="cylindrical">Cylindrical</option>
  </select>
  <br /><br />
  <lable for="radius">Radius : </lable>
  <input type="number" id="radius" /><br />
  <lable for="shapeWidth">Widht : </lable>
  <input type="number" id="shapeWidth" /><br />
  <lable for="shapeHeight">Height :</lable>
  <input type="number" id="shapeHeight" />
  <hr />
  <label for="area" id="area_result">Area :</label>
  <label for="area_result"></label>
  <br />
  <label for="primiter" id="primiter_result">Primiter :</label>
  <label for="primiter_result"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: that's great thanks a million times body.

Answer (score 0):

Her is a vanilla JS version

I fixed some spelling and added a "please select"

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // when the page has loaded
  document.getElementById("shapes").addEventListener("change", function() { // when the select is changed
    document.getElementById("radius").disabled = ["rectangle","square"].includes(this.value); // disable if square or rectangle. 
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <hr class="lighter">
  <label for="shapes">Shapes :</label>
  <select name="shapes" id="shapes">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="rectangle">Rectangle</option>
    <option value="square">Square</option>
    <option value="circle">Circle</option>
    <option value="cylindrical">Cylindrical</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <label for="radius">Radius : </label>
  <input type="number" id="radius" ><br>
  <label for="shapeWidth">Width : </label>
  <input type="number" id="shapeWidth"><br>
  <label for="shapeHeight">Height :</label>
  <input type="number" id="shapeHeight">
  <hr>
  <label for="area" id="area_result">Area :</label>
  <label for="area_result"></label>
  <br>
  <label for="perimeter" id="perimeter_result">Perimeter :</label>
  <label for="perimeter_result"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `label` element should not be treated like the majority of other HTML elements in that it is not supposed to be used without being referenced to an `input` element of some type. So you should not use them to present content such as the calculation results as you do!

If you use a `form` around these various input controls you can use the often overlooked `dotted notation` to access these various form elements ( though many browsers permit accessing elements directly by ID without even requiring `document.getElementById` these days since HTML5 ) which is useful within any routines to perform the calculations as it reduces the code required.

```js
// precision for floats
const precision=3;

const d=document;

// get reference to the parent form
const f=d.forms.calculator;

// event handler
const evthandler=function(e){
  
  // ensure all disabled elements are re-enabled
  f.querySelectorAll('input:disabled').forEach( input => input.disabled=false );
  
  // named form inputs/outputs etc
  let oSel=f.shapes;
  let oArea=f.area;
  let oPer=f.perimeter;
  let oRad=f.radius;
  let oWidth=f.shapeWidth;
  let oHeight=f.shapeHeight;
  
  // The currently selected `option`
  let option=oSel.options[ oSel.options.selectedIndex ];

  // access a named dataset to identify which elements to disable.
  if( option.dataset.disable!=null ){
     f[ option.dataset.disable ].disabled=true;
  }
  
  // do the calculations and show the results...
  oArea.textContent=area( oSel.value, oWidth.value, oHeight.value, oRad.value );
  oPer.textContent=perimeter( oSel.value, oWidth.value, oHeight.value, oRad.value );
};







const area=(shape,w,h,r)=>{
  switch( shape ){
    case 'square':
    case 'rectangle':return w * h;
    case 'circle':return ( Math.PI * Math.pow( r, 2 ) ).toFixed(precision);
    case 'cylindrical':return ( 2 * Math.PI * Math.pow( r, 2 ) + 2 * Math.PI * r * h ).toFixed(precision);
  }
};
const perimeter=(shape,w,h,r)=>{
  switch( shape ){
    case 'square':return 4 * Math.min(w,h);
    case 'rectangle':return ( 2 * w ) + ( 2 * h );
    case 'circle':return ( Math.PI * r * 2 ).toFixed(precision);
    case 'cylindrical': return ( 2 * ( Math.PI * ( r * 2 ) ) ).toFixed(precision);
  }
};






// assign the delegated event handler to respond to any change events
f.addEventListener('change', evthandler )
```

```css
label{display:block;width:40%;clear:both;padding:0.5rem;}
label input,label select{float:right;width:60%;padding:0.25rem}
hr{margin:1rem 0}
output{color:green}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <hr class='lighter'>
  <!--
    Form added to group together form elements and allow
    named access using dot notation.
    
    labels correctly spelled and inputs nested within
    so that <br /> tags can be replaced with CSS blocks
    
    Added a dataset ( data-disable )
  -->
  <form name='calculator'>
    <label>Shapes :
      <select name='shapes'>
        <option disabled hidden selected>Please select
        <option data-disable='radius' value='rectangle'>Rectangle</option>
        <option data-disable='radius' value='square'>Square</option>
        <option value='circle'>Circle</option>
        <option value='cylindrical'>Cylindrical</option>
      </select>
    </label>



    <label>Radius: <input type='number' name='radius' min=0 step=1></label>
    <label>Width: <input type='number' name='shapeWidth' min=0 step=1></label>
    <label>Height: <input type='number' name='shapeHeight' min=0 step=1></label>

    <hr />
    
    <!--
      output tags for displaying output rather than labels.
    -->
    <label>Area: <output name='area'></output></label>
    <label>Perimeter: <output name='perimeter'></output></label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Woah, that is a bunch of code to lay on a beginner. They did not ask you to write his complete script.

Comment: I got carried away - too much coffee

Comment: I know the feeling ;)